# error when insert new values into database in infinityfree

Tags: mysql, insert, hosting

When i use InfinityFree hosting, my register form doesn't work. But in localhost it's no problem.

I am trying to insert into my `phpmyadmin` database. The first column is the `user_id` column an it's an `auto_increment` field.

if i do this :

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`user_id`, `email`, `username`, `password`, `game_id`) VALUES('', '$email', '$username', '$password', '$game_id')
```

the error is :

> Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'user_id' at row 1

and if i do this :

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`user_id`, `email`, `username`, `password`, `game_id`) VALUES(NULL, '$email', '$username', '$password', '$game_id')
```

the error is :

> Data truncated for column 'game_id' at row 1

Comment: 1. You dont specify a column name in `INSERT` statement if you are not assigning `VALUES` to it 2. You havent specified your datatypes and values you are attempting to insert but its likely that the supplied value is wider than the datatype for `game_id`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning a NULL value to *user_id*, just leave the *user_id* out of the query.

**It should be like this:**

```
INSERT INTO user (email, username, password, game_id) VALUES('$email', '$username', '$password', '$game_id')
```